# Is JSON appropriate for indexing large filesystems?

Tags: python, json, indexing

The task at hand is simple: all file names and their respective directories  are to be stored in an index file. Right now, it is a plain text file (compressed). I was wondering if JSON is fit for the job. I am using a script written in Python to do this. It walks through all the directories and saves them in a paragraph format. I compress them at the end too. It is fairly fast - about 15 seconds for indexing 70,000 files and 7,500 folders (including compress time). The size of the index file is about 300 KB

```
this/is/the/folder
file1.png
file2.txt
file3.dat

another/folder
morefiles.inf
saywhaaa.mov
```

The parser for this index file is simple. The first line in each paragraph is the top folder, and the remaining lines are file names contained inside that folder. Keeping the "don't fix it if it isn't broken" policy in mind, I thought if using JSON could've any advantages here? Is it quicker to parse the data? Will the index file increase in size? I don't know any JSON, but I will learn it if it would help my case.

Comment: With python, the easiest way to think of JSON is that it just a 'dumb' dictionary (can't hold python specific information like classes or functions, or special objects). So if your data can easily be put into a python dictionary, simply do a `import json` at the top, and instead of writing the dictionary to a file, do `file.write(json.loads(my_dict))` and see if it's faster or makes more sense to you.

Comment: @CasualDemon Thank you. I shall try that.

Comment: I honestly imagine that your parser will be faster, as it is purpose built. And your file size will be smaller, because it won't require all the extra characters and structure. What JSON will gain you is portability. So for example if you suddenly want to send it to a webpage and mess with it in JavaScript, you don't have to rebuild your parser in another language. So if this is a one off program that probably won't be extended, your method is probably the better option.